# Where I can download the Official Mockito jar files for use with Apache ant project in Eclipse?

Tags: java, jar, ant, mockito

I just can't find any of the official mockito's jar files to download directly for use within my apache ant project.

Where can I find them?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Maven, then you can find jar in Maven Repository online.
https://mvnrepository.com/search?q=mockito

Comment: As the question states. I'm not using Maven. I'm using apache ant.

Comment: A jar for apache ant is the same as a jar for maven.  The jars you want are there, where Holinc suggested.